# Elemento filho atrás do pai

Tags: css, posicionamento, z-index

Tenho dois elementos pai e filho com position fixed em ambos, como faço para o filho ficar atrás do pai? 
Tenho um menu bottom (pai), quando clicado abre o submenu (filho) com animação surgindo atrás do menu.

Comment: usa index https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Não funciona, por padrão o filho pega o z index do pai.

Comment: Cara coloca seu código inteiro ai, adita a pergunta e coloca o HTML e CSS do seu menu com pai, filho etc... Só assim da para te dar uma resposta mais precisa.

Comment: Oi Charles! Podes dar um exemplo do HTML e CSS que já tens. Assim fica mais fácil de ajudar e dar uma resposta acertada.

Comment: Poste seu códico para que possamos te ajudar, e ter uma resposta mais precisa como já foi dita.

Answer (score -1):

Coloque o atributo: `z-index: -1;` no elemento filho. Isso o deixará atrás do elemento pai